# onChange of a Material UI TextField is not working (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

I am making a form with Material UI in React to send data to MongoDB. What happens is that in my form I have elements like DatePickers, Select, TextField, all from Material UI.

So I have the following code to make the change of the states:

```
const [project, setProject] = useState({
    project_start: null,
    project_end: null,
    project_name: "",
    usersId: [],
    partnerId: "",
    categoryId: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (name, newVal) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [name]: newVal });
  };
```

And this would be a summary of what my form consists of:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<Box width="50%">
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DatePicker
                    id="project_start"
                    name="project_start"
                    value={project.project_start}
                    onChange={handleChange.bind(null, "project_start")}
                    slotProps={{
                      textField: {
                        size: "small",
                        margin: "dense",
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
                <TextField
                  id="nombreP"
                  name="project_name"
                  value={project.project_name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  margin="dense"
                  size="small"
                />
                <FormControl size="small" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                  <Select
                    id="encargadoP"
                    multiple
                    name="usersId"
                    value={project.usersId}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      handleChange(
                        "usersId",
                        typeof e.target.value === "string"
                          ? e.target.value.split(",")
                          : e.target.value
                      )
                    }
                    MenuProps={MenuProps}
                    renderValue={(selected) => (
                      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
                        {selected.map((value) => (
                          <Chip key={value} label={value} />
                        ))}
                      </Box>
                    )}
                    sx={{ width: 205 }}
                  >
                    {data?.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                      <MenuItem key={_id} value={name}>
                        {name}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant={"outlined"}
              size={"large"}
              sx={{
                width: 420,
                border: "1px solid white",
                m: "3rem 0 0 0",
                color: "white",
                borderRadius: "30px",
              }}
            >
              Agregar proyecto
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </form>
```

At the moment the onChange of the TextField does not work, when I write something it does not appear. So I would like to ask, how could I change it?

I am very grateful to people who can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution, if you combine TJ Crowder's answer with the code you already have, is given in your `Select` component:

```
                  <Select
                    id="encargadoP"
                    multiple
                    name="usersId"
                    value={project.usersId}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      handleChange(
                        "usersId",
                        typeof e.target.value === "string"
                          ? e.target.value.split(",")
                          : e.target.value
                      )
                    }
```

You can do largely the same thing in your `TextField` component:

```
             <TextField
                  id="nombreP"
                  name="project_name"
                  value={project.project_name}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                      handleChange(
                        "project_name",
                        e.target.value
                      )
                    }
```

Comment: I did it this way and it worked, thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props), your `handleChange` isn't what `TextField` expects `onChange` to look like. It expects your function to accept the usual single parameter, an event object, and then get the field name and value from that. For example:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    setProject({ ...project, [name]: value });
};
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I had it that way before, but this way the DatePicker stops working

The [`DatePicker` `onChange` is different](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props), so you can't use one function for both.

You might have one function that makes the change, and have each `onChange` call that function though.

```
const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setProject({ ...project, [name]: value });
};
const handleTextChange = ({currentTarget: { name, value }}) =>
    handleChange(name, value);
const handleDatePickerChange = handleChange.bind("project_start");
// ...
```

Comment: I had it that way before, but this way the DatePicker stops working :c

Comment: @ValentinaLoaiza then you're going to need a different function for the DatePicker onChange

Comment: @ValentinaLoaiza or do for the Text field something similar to what you did with Select.

Comment: @ValentinaLoaiza - I've updated the answer to respond to your comment.